# Trying to use VLookup across worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have tried to use a VLookup code on a worksheet to use VLookup function to find prices on worksheet Parts list then fill this into worksheet Job Card Master using code in column D to fill column O to lastrow.
The code won't run the error says

> "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Private Sub Up_Date_Prices_Click()

        Dim JCM As Worksheet, PartsList As Worksheet
        Dim JCMLastRow As Long, PartsListLastRow As Long, x As Long
        Dim DataRng As Range
       
        
        
        Set JCM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Card Master")
        Set PartsList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Parts List")
        
        JCMLastRow = JCM.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        PartsListLastRow = PartsList.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        
        Set DataRng = PartsList.Range("A2:B" & PartsListLastRow)
        
        For x = 13 To JCMLastRow
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
           JCM.Range("O" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                JCM.Range("D" & x).Value.DataRng, 2, False)
        
        Next x
  
End Sub
```

Comment: `JCM.Range("D" & x).Value.DataRng` should be `JCM.Range("D" & x).Value, DataRng`

Comment: Looks like a typo, a `.` dot was typed where a `,` comma is needed, causing the vlookup function to be missing a parameter, and the `lookup_value` parameter to be an invalid expression.